# About the use of @ in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I was reading the book of Dave Thomas, *"Agile Web Development with Rails"*, Fourth Edition. Inside a class named **Cart**, he called an attribute named "line_items" provided by a relationship between the classes **Cart** and **LineItem**.

Inside the method that uses this attribute int the **Cart** class, the attribute is called without the "@" that is used when we invoke the attributes of a instance. Can someone say to me why this work? Because I was expecting that he had used the "@" symbol. The code is shown below:

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
 def add_product(product_id)
 #In this line below, I was expecting @lineitems.find_by ..... 
  current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)
  if current_item
   current_item.quantity += 1
  else
   current_item = line_items.build(:product_id => product_id)
  end
  current_item
 end 
end
```

Comment: Associations create methods that return the associated values. Associated values are not instance variables, however.

Answer (score 4):

This works because `has_many` creates a reader and writer method for `line_items`--in a similar way that using `attr_accessor` creates reader and writer methods for that attribute name. It's very similar to the following:

```
class Cart
  def line_items
    @line_items
  end

  def line_items=(value)
    @line_items = value
  end
end
```

Rails creates many such methods for you, including ones for each column of the database for the model you're using, as well as ones for all associations (such as `line_items` here).

See [chapter 4 of "A Guide to Active Record Associations"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference) in the Rails Guides for details on what methods are added for a specific association.

Comment: As a note, an `attr_accessor` is often measurably faster than an accessor method you make yourself due to internal optimizations even if they are often functionally equivalent.